# Bootstrap 4 column ordering usecase

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am looking for a real world use case for column ordering in Bootstrap 4.

I understand how it works, but to increase this understanding, I'd like to see some examples of why you would use it.

Here are the docs:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#order-classes
To be clear, I am looking for use cases of why to use it, not how to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used column ordering to change the order of an image and accompanying text based on the device size. For small devices I showed the text first, then the image, while for larger devices I had the image on left with the text on the right.

Answer (score 0):

I often use it for alternating layouts in a list. Like having 3 entries each with a image and a text and i want the second one to be exact opposite layout of the other two but only on desktop. On mobile there should be the image first always.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
      Image
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
      Text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 order-md-2">
      Image
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 order-md-1">
      Text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
      Image
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
      Text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Result Desktop:

```
Image | Text
Text  | Image
Image | Text
```

Result Mobile:

```
Image
Text
-----
Image
Text
-----
Image
Text
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, column ordering is used to create different layouts on different screen widths. Here's are some use cases, most of which are used to prioritize vertical content on mobile/smaller devices.

**Prioritize important content first on mobile.** - A very typical use-case is a simple 2 column layout with a left sidebar, and a main content area.

[image]

[image]

Column ordering, allows us to reverse the order on mobile so that the sidebar (less important content) stacks vertically under the main content.

**Prioritize navigation on mobile.** This use-case is similar. Suppose the layout had a right sidebar that contained navigation which we want first on mobile. Once again ordering could be used to reverse the layout on mobile.